# Как переделать метод на stream api

Tags: java, массивы, list, java-stream

Как переделать метод на Stream API:

```
public class ConvertList {
    public List<Integer> convert(List<int[]> list) {
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int[] i : list) {
            for (int j : i) {
                result.add(j);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Метод принимать лист с массивами интов и должен вернуть лист только со интами.

Вот тест:

```
public class ConvertListTest {
@Test
public void convertTest() {
    ConvertList convertList = new ConvertList();
    List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new int[]{1, 2}, new int[]{3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, new int[]{8, 9}));
    List result = convertList.convert(list);
    List<Integer> expected = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9));
    assertThat(result, is(expected));
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 return list.stream()
         .flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream)
         .boxed()
         .collect(toList());
```